# Add days to date using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-events

I am trying to add days to a given date using Javascript. I have the following code:

```
function onChange(e) {
    var datepicker = $("#DatePicker").val();
    alert(datepicker);
    var joindate = new Date(datepicker);
    alert(joindate);
    var numberOfDaysToAdd = 1;
    joindate.setDate(joindate + numberOfDaysToAdd);
    var dd = joindate.getDate();
    var mm = joindate.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = joindate.getFullYear();
    var joinFormattedDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
    $('.new').val(joinFormattedDate);
}
```

On first alert I get the date `24/06/2011` but on second alert I get `Thu Dec 06 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)` which is wrong I want it to remain `24/06/2011` so that I can add days to it. In my code I want my final output to be `25/06/2011`.

Fiddle is @ http://jsfiddle.net/tassadaque/rEe4v/

Comment: The date should be *m/d/yyyy* otherwise you'll get unexpected results. See my answer for explanation.

Comment: and mine, and gedrox' and Alnitak's. All point this out before you did...

Comment: @mplungjan and mine is the only one that actually uses the DatePicker itself to return the right `Date` object...

Comment: See my comment on your answer. I think the whole function posted by @Tassadaque can be replaced with `$('.new').val($("#DatePicker").datepicker( "setDate" , +1 ));`

Comment: @mplungjan no, because `.datePicker("setDate")` **doesn't return a value**.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Date('string')` will attempt to parse the string as `m/d/yyyy`. The string `24/06/2011` thus becomes `Dec 6, 2012`. Reason: 24 is treated as a month... 1 => January 2011, 13 => January 2012 hence 24 => December 2012. I hope you understand what I mean. So:

```
var dmy = "24/06/2011".split("/");        // "24/06/2011" should be pulled from $("#DatePicker").val() instead
var joindate = new Date(
    parseInt(dmy[2], 10),
    parseInt(dmy[1], 10) - 1,
    parseInt(dmy[0], 10)
);
alert(joindate);                          // Fri Jun 24 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (West Asia Standard Time) 
joindate.setDate(joindate.getDate() + 1); // substitute 1 with actual number of days to add
alert(joindate);                          // Sat Jun 25 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (West Asia Standard Time)
alert(
    ("0" + joindate.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" +
    ("0" + (joindate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" +
    joindate.getFullYear()
);
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/rEe4v/11/)

Comment: I think we have already established this several times before your answer.

Comment: @mplungjan: no one has pointed out precisely why the month/date becomes Dec/2012. Just trying to help.

Comment: I am getting Inalid Date alerts

Comment: Yes I said: _the second is the generated date from a non-US formatted date._ Alnitak said _you're trying to parse the text-value of the DatePicker, when that's not in the right format for your locale._

Comment: @Tassadaque: the example above on its own should not generate any invalid date. Which alert is invalid? The first one? If so, can you tell me what does `$("#DatePicker").val()` give you?

Comment: @Tassadaque: Come on man, where is the `.split("/")`? See [updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/rEe4v/3/).

Comment: Sorry about that trying to many solutions. At last some thing that did the trick can i change the output date in  "dd/mm/yyyy" format

Comment: Done! using dateFormat(joindate,"dd/mm/yyyy") Thanks. Initially i wasn't thinking that culture will cause so much problem

Comment: Hmm I find it very strange that you accept this answer since mine - including a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/wUqPy/) but not with the words DEMO HERE written as big as this - has the identical result plus a lot more investigation

Comment: @mplungjan I wish I could accept more than one answer. I was following his answer before yours and it solves the problem so I accepted it BEFORE HE ADDED THE DEMO HERE LINK TO his answer as it should be evident from the comments above. I appreciate your effort and hope to find your help in future :)

Answer (score 5):

I would like to encourage you to use [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) library. It is really awesome!

```
function onChange(e) {
    var date = Date.parse($("#DatePicker").val()); //You might want to tweak this to as per your needs.
    var new_date = date.add(n).days();
    $('.new').val(new_date.toString('M/d/yyyy'); //You might want to tweak this as per your needs as well.
}
```

Comment: Incredible overkill. Especially if datePicker can do the job itself

Comment: @mplungjan possibly, although it is subjective, in any reasonable application however Date manipulations are a given, something like DateJS helps you very neat & simple code, I think it is definitely worth the small footprint that it brings along with it. Today you want to just add days, tomorrow you might want to do more.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming *numberOfDaysToAdd* is a number:

```
joindate.setDate(joindate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
```

Answer (score 4):

The first alert is the value of the field. the second is the generated date from a non-US formatted date.

## [Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/wUqPy/)

(seems that this kind of markup is necessary to get noticed)

If you want to keep your code, then you need to change

`var joindate = new Date(datepicker);`

to

```
var parms = datepicker.split("/");
```

then use

```
var joindate = new Date(parms[1]+"/"+parms[0]+"/"+parms[2]);
```

OR the identically working

```
var joindate = new Date(parms[2],parms[1]-1,parms[0]);
```

As pointed out in a few other answers too, use the .getDate()

```
joindate.setDate(joindate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
```

Lastly you want to add a 0 if the month is < 10

```
if (mm<10) mm="0"+mm;
```

---

If you are using the datepicker from jQuery UI, then you can do

`$('.new').val($("#DatePicker").datepicker( "setDate" , +1 ).val());`

instead of your function

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-setDate

> Sets the current date for the
>   datepicker. The new date may be a Date
>   object or a string in the current date
>   format (e.g. '01/26/2009'), a number
>   of days from today (e.g. +7) or a
>   string of values and periods ('y' for
>   years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks,
>   'd' for days, e.g. '+1m +7d'), or null
>   to clear the selected date.

Comment: Error is removed but joinFormattedDate is giving me NaN/NaN/NaN :(

Comment: `Date(Date.parse("..."))` is redundant. Just use `Date("...")`.

Comment: joindate.setDate(joindate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);

Comment: @mplungjan I wish I could accept more than one answer. I was following his answer before yours and it solves the problem so I accepted it BEFORE HE ADDED THE DEMO HERE LINK TO his answer as it should be evident from the comments above. I appreciate your effort and hope to find your help in future :) –

Comment: @Tassadaque - did you try my jQuery datepicker suggestion instead of the plain javascript one? And you have enough points to at least vote up.

Comment: @mplungjan u could have used different color for "Here is Working Example" :P

Comment: Actually i am using telerik datepicker and vote is up I was little late to react :)

Comment: In [telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/datepicker/clientapi/defaultcs.aspx) I saw `var datePicker = $find("RadDatePicker1"); var date = datePicker.get_selectedDate(); if (datePicker.isEmpty()) date = new Date();date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); datePicker.set_selectedDate(date);`

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
function onChange(e) {
        var datepicker = $("#DatePicker").val();
        alert(datepicker);
        var parts = datepicker.split(/[^\d]/);
        var joindate = new Date();
        joindate.setFullYear(parts[2], parts[1]-1, parts[0]);
        alert(joindate);
        var numberOfDaysToAdd = 1;
        joindate.setDate(joindate + numberOfDaysToAdd);
        var dd = joindate.getDate();
        var mm = joindate.getMonth() + 1;
        var y = joindate.getFullYear();
        var joinFormattedDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
        $('.new').val(joinFormattedDate);

    }
```

I suppose the problem is JavaScript expects format MM/DD/YYYY not DD/MM/YYYY when passed into Date constructor.

Comment: I also think of the same when i alert joinFormattedDate it gives me NaN/NaN/NaN

Comment: Why use two statements to set the date? var joindate = new Date(parts[2], parts[1]-1, parts[0]); will work and make more sense than overloading setFullYear. You are also missing the joindate.getDate()+

Answer (score 2):

To answer your real problem, I think your issue is that you're trying to parse the text-value of the DatePicker, when that's not in the right format for your locale.

Instead of `.val()`, use:

```
var joindate = $('#DatePicker').datepicker("getDate");
```

to get the underyling `Date()` object representing the selected date directly from jQuery.

This guarantees that the date object is correct *regardless of the date format specified in the `DatePicker` or the current locale*.

Then use:

```
joindate.setDate(joindate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
```

to move it on.

Comment: @mplungjan a `Date()` object is internally just a millisecond offset since the epoch.  How can it be "incorrect" ?

Comment: The date is incorrect if you construct the date with a non-US formatted date, e.g. dd/mm/yyyy and expect it to be correct. You have since changed your answer to be more understandable.

Comment: Documentation suggests .datepicker( "setDate" , +1 )

Comment: @mplungjan that'll change what's currently showing in the date picker, but you'd still have to use `getDate` to retrieve the value.

Comment: Sure, but there would be no need to getDate at all if all you want is to add a day

Comment: @mplungjan Sure there is, if you want to copy it into another field (like the OP's code does).

Answer (score 1):

Is it a typo round joindate.setDate(joindate + numberOfDaysToAdd)?

I tried this code, it seems ok to me

```
    var joindate = new Date(2010, 5, 24);
    alert(joindate);
    var numberOfDaysToAdd = 1;
    joindate.setDate(joindate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
    var dd = joindate.getDate();
    var mm = joindate.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = joindate.getFullYear();
    var joinFormattedDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
    alert(joinFormattedDate);
```

Comment: You fixed half the problem. First get a correct date. The .getDate() was the second issue

Answer (score 1):

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    this.setDate(this.getDate() + days);
    return this;
};
```

and in your javascript code you could call

```
var currentDate = new Date();
// to add 8 days to current date
currentDate.addDays(8);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onChange(e) {
    var datepicker = $("#DatePicker").val().split("/");
    var joindate = new Date();
    var numberOfDaysToAdd = 1;
    joindate.setFullYear(parseInt(datepicker[2]), parseInt(datepicker[1])-1, parseInt(datepicker[0])+numberOfDaysToAdd);
    $('.new').val(joindate);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/k4GM5/

Comment: Actually my datepicker has value "26/06/2011" instead of "06/24/2011" which is the root cause i think if i change ur fiddle it says invaliddate and when i run it gives me wrong date

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
Date.prototype.addDay = function(numberOfDaysToAdd){
    this.setTime(this.getTime() + (numberOfDaysToAdd * 86400000));
};

function onChange(e) {
        var date = new Date(Date.parse($("#DatePicker").val()));
        date.addDay(1);
        var dd = date.getDate();
        var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
        var y =  date.getFullYear();
        var joinFormattedDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
        $('.new').val(joinFormattedDate);
    }
```

Comment: This does **not** answer the question in a _useful_ way. **why** do you believe this is the answer? **how** does it work? Simply telling someone to _change their code_ or just _giving someone working code_ without any context or meaning does not help them learn what they did wrong, and is also not as useful for future readers.